# Simple, current how-to install mod-security on cPanel server?

Tags: mod-security

Does anyone have or know of a simple, up to date how to for installing mod-security on cPanel and configuring it after install?

Every how to on the web I've found is at least two years old and is based on a mod-security addon function in cPanel which doesn't exist anymore.

There are a couple of free add ons to simplify selecting rule files (configserver's for example) but there's no documentation on which rules a cPanel system "should" be using and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent installation guide can be found at
http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/2.5.12/html-multipage/installation.html

Once it is installed you can use the configserver's manager for it.